# how to change odoo Boolean field Value Based on logged in user?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

i'm trying to make a boolean field computed based on the user

because this boolean field value used to hide som important buttons, and in it's condition to check user_id field form another object to compare it with self.user_id and put the value, so if the user not as current user it should be false and that's done , but if i logged with the other user the value still False , so how that can be done

this my code

```
class uservalidate(models.Model):
_inherit = 'stock.picking'

@api.depends('location_dest_id','partner_id')
def is_has_access_true(self):
    if self.location_dest_id.manager == self.user_id:
        self.is_has_access = True
    else:
        self.is_has_access= False
    pass
is_has_access = fields.Boolean(string="" ,compute='is_has_access_true'  )
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the stock-picking `Responsible` (self.user_id) which is different from the current user and your condition does not take into consideration the current user.

You can face that problem when the same user who created the pickings is used to check the condition.

To check if the current user is a manager use `self.env.user` instead of `self.user_id`.

If you need to check if the current user has `read` access, you can use a [check_access_rights](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/models.py#L3209) method that verifies that the operation is given by `operation` is allowed for the current user according to the access rights.

```
if records.check_access_rights('read'):
```

Comment: I've updated the code on my own with self.env.user, and boolean field values change as I need, but I don't know why the button is still invisible for the user who should validate it
this the button 

            <xpath expr="//button[@name='button_validate']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': ['|','|', ('state', 'in', ('waiting','confirmed')), ('show_validate', '=', False),('is_has_access', '=', False)]}</attribute>
            </xpath>

Comment: The field visibility depends also on `show_validate` and `state` fields (Using `OR` operator).

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way to get logged in user id:

```
self.env.user.id
```